# How do you validate a field set with Jquery datepicker without disabling input

Tags: jquery, datepicker, validation

I can't disable the input, but I need to validate it no matter what the datepicker does.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({minDate: 0, maxDate: +7});
```

This produces the calendar I want, but won't validate the input field. 
I have the validator plugin already in use requiring fields so I'd like to stick to that. 
This code will check if the field is required, but it won't check the max date:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#form").validate({
   rules: {
    datepicker: {
      required: true,
      date: true,
       maxDate: 7
          }
         }
       });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kV5hk/), your js code should work.
Enter `10/22/2011` into the input field and press `submit`. The max date will be checked.

You can remove the `maxDate` row in your `rules`, it will be ignored.

Comment: I suppose this is right then, but it still doesn't solve my problem, I'm guessing its out of date jquery or something.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, "maxDate" is not a valid rule in vaildate plugin, so that's probably why it doesn't validate. Although, you can create custom rules using [addMethod](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod).